# Create multiple tables of same class in hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate

In my java project using hibernate, I have a class named Employee.java.
I want to create employee table every month with table name as 'Employee_MMYYYY' (MM-Month YYYY-Year).
  I have tried by creating my own naming startegy and configuring the same in Configuration object of org.hibernate.cfg. 
 But the issue i am facing is, my effort is resulting in creation of only one table. I am not able to create multiple tables. 
Can any one throw some light on this?

Comment: why create new table?

Comment: Why not build the table by month first? 
Only 120 pieces were built 10 years ago？

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why you want do that but best way is use oracle enterprise database and add partition to your table by range or list , it's way to get better performance . if you need millions of rows do that , but if you need practice about something or find some way to create new table with Month in hibernate , better know hibernate haven't this feature so , you can create a shell program or something like (or use java to create new hibernate xml configurations).
don't use annotation in javabeans and use xml files.
look at this : https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E18283_01/server.112/e16541/part_admin001.htm

```
CREATE TABLE sales
  ( prod_id       NUMBER(6)
  , cust_id       NUMBER
  , time_id       DATE
  , channel_id    CHAR(1)
  , promo_id      NUMBER(6)
  , quantity_sold NUMBER(3)
  , amount_sold   NUMBER(10,2)
  )
 PARTITION BY RANGE (time_id) SUBPARTITION BY HASH (cust_id)
  SUBPARTITIONS 8 STORE IN (ts1, ts2, ts3, ts4)
 ( PARTITION sales_q1_2006 VALUES LESS THAN (TO_DATE('01-APR-2006','dd-MON-yyyy'))
 , PARTITION sales_q2_2006 VALUES LESS THAN (TO_DATE('01-JUL-2006','dd-MON-yyyy'))
 , PARTITION sales_q3_2006 VALUES LESS THAN (TO_DATE('01-OCT-2006','dd-MON-yyyy'))
 , PARTITION sales_q4_2006 VALUES LESS THAN (TO_DATE('01-JAN-2007','dd-MON-yyyy'))
 );
```